# How can I specify max memory per core for a Slurm job

Tags: memory, slurm

I want to specify max amount of memory per core for a batch job in slurm

I can see two sbatch memory options:

```
--mem=MB            maximum amount of real memory per node  required by the job.
--mem-per-cpu=mem   amount of real memory per allocated CPU required by the job.
```

either of those options suits  my needs

any suggestions how to achive this goal

Answer (score 6):

You can use `--mem=MaxMemPerNode` to use the maximum allowed memory for the job in that node. if configured in the cluster, you can see the value `MaxMemPerNode` using `scontrol show config`.

A special case, setting `--mem=0` will also give the job access to all of the memory on each node.(This is not ideal in a heterogeneous cluster since, the lowest memory value among the nodes will only be used for all the allocated nodes).

If configured in the cluster, `--mem-per-cpu=MaxMemPerCPU` can be used to enable using the maximum allowed memory per cpu.